# Scroll button hide after 5 seconds using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, scroll

I can scroll on the top or the bottom of my page. But after 5seconds, I want my scroll div disapear. I use the property delay & hide of Jquery. 
I must refresh my page to works my code once my div disapear.

```
$(function () {

        var scrollTrigger = 100, // px
                backToTop = function () {
                    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
                    if (scrollTop > scrollTrigger) {

                        $("a[href='#top']").addClass('show').delay(2000).hide(500);
                        $("a[href='#bottom']").addClass('show').delay(2000).hide(500);

                    } else {
                        $("a[href='#top']").removeClass('show');
                        $("a[href='#bottom']").removeClass('show');
                    }
                };
        backToTop();

        $(window).on('scroll', function () {
            backToTop();
        });
        $("a[href='#top']").click(function() {
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
            return false;
        });

        $("a[href='#bottom']").click(function() {
        $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 9999 }, 'slow');
        return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: what exactly is your problem

Comment: @madalinivascu Once my scroll div disapear and I scroll ; the scroll div doesn"t reappear. I must refresh my page to works my code.

Comment: why do you want them to disappear ?

Comment: @Pawan I want the div scroll disapear after 5 seconds

Comment: and after those 5 second how will you show the links again?

Comment: @madalinivascu because this is not very pretty to keep the div scroll. No Once the user scroll again, the scroll div can reappear. I don't know how after 5 seconds the links show again that the problem :w

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the setTimeout()  function. 
ref.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp,
https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-settimeout-function-examples/

example

```
               backToTop = function () {

                    $("a[href='#top']").show(500);
                    $("a[href='#bottom']").show(500);

                setTimeout(function() {
                    $("a[href='#top']").hide(500);
                    $("a[href='#bottom']").hide(500);
                }, 5000)
            };
```

Comment: After 5 seconds, I want my link dissapear. But if the user scroll again, the links must appear !

Comment: @MasterSinge how was it?

Comment: Thank you so much @AndrinDanganan :p !!!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function :

```
var goToTop = function(){
  window.scrollTo(0,/*y-coordinate (should be 0 if well-designed website)*/);
  setTimeout(function(){$(this).hide(500);},5000);
}
```

Use it as a click event bind on your button just like :

```
$(document).ready(
  $(my button JQ selector).click(goToTop);
);
```

Then, when you scroll you should show(500)'it again.